# How to integrate only specific files in a git fork?

Tags: git

I have a repo that I forked and I made some modifications (mainly in the frontend).

I would like to maintain two repos, and integrate the backend improvements from the old one into the new one, while keeping the front-end changes in the new one.

I tried merging the branches but it simply overwrites the changes I made and leads to a conflict. How can I do what I want to do while maintaining the two independent repos?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around the problem by merging the branch with the `--no-commit` flag then back out the files you don't want to modify.

```
git merge --no-commit forky/mybranch
git checkout <FILE/FOLDER> HEAD
git merge --continue
```

Comment: Thank you! So in your example forky/mybranch is the original branch and file/folder are the files I do NOT want to modify?

Comment: Right. Any files you specify will be reset to HEAD. Ie unchanged.